# How do i Fix django.db.utils.DatabaseError

Tags: django, database, mongodb, djongo

How do i fix Django Database error. I'm using MongoDB with Djongo.

Everything was working fine until recently when i decided to add NewApp. Whenever i try to migrate it greets me with django.db.utils.DatabaseError .

I tried reseting the DataBase Manually as well as from Terminal but had no luck.

I think it's super simple but imm new to Django and MongoDB can't seem to figure out how to fix it, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's what the error looks like.

```
Not implemented alter command for SQL ALTER TABLE "articles_article" ADD COLUMN "author_id" int NOT NULL
  Applying articles.0002_article_author...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 783, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 875, in parse
    raise e
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 856, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 888, in _alter
    query = AlterQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 425, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 435, in parse
    self._add(statement)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 598, in _add
    raise SQLDecodeError(err_key=tok.value,
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

    Keyword: int
    Sub SQL: ALTER TABLE "articles_article" ADD COLUMN "author_id" int NOT NULL
    FAILED SQL: ('ALTER TABLE "articles_article" ADD COLUMN "author_id" int NOT NULL',)
    Params: ([],)
    Version: 1.3.3

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 110, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 480, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/restApi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: hi there, I have the same issue. Have you fixed it?

Comment: I did a fake migrations which does the job, but don't think it is a right solution.

Comment: oh me too, I did a fake migration. I thought it went right, but ...

Answer (score 3):

Hi this happens frequently. Here's what to do in three simple steps

1. Go to the migrations directory of your app
2. delete 0001_initial.py or allnumbers_initial.py
3. Run makemigrations and migrate again. your problem will definitely be solved.

Answer (score 3):

1. `pip install sqlparse ==0.2.4`
2. Go to migration directory
3. Delete 0001_intial.py
4. `python manage.py makemigrations`
5. `python manage.py migrate`
6. `python manage.py runserver`
7. You will able to login: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this same error and if none of the other mentioned methods work than it might be that you have wrong version of sqlparse. Mine was 0.4.1 and that doesnot work for some region. You have to have the version 0.2.4.

```
pip install sqlparse==0.2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too. I solved it by upgrading Django from 2.1.7 to 3.1.7, deleting the migration file and running makemigrations again. Then, when I migrated, there was no more error. Apparently the migration file generated by Django 2.1.7 is different from 3.1.7.

**EDIT**:
If you get the same error when querying using "filter", try downgrading your Django version to 3.0.5.

Comment: Zharfan do you know make threaded comments system?

Comment: Sorry @orynnnnn I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Django version 3.0.5 worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

pip install --install-option="--extras-require=json" git+https://github.com/nesdis/djongo.git@master

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all migrations (with migrations folder) and it is solved

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33033295)