# Django + Mongo + djongo. Trouble with adding new models with ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

i use django + mongo with djongo. I have 2 models: Deck and Card;

```
class Deck(models.Model):
deckName = models.TextField(max_length=100)
deckDetail = models.TextField(max_length=1400)

class Card(models.Model):
cardName = models.TextField(max_length=100)
cardDetail = models.TextField(max_length=1400)
deckCard = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
dailyCard = models.BooleanField(default=False, unique=True)
```

when i add new Deck model with http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app/deck/add/ (django admin standart) it's ok. But when i add new Card model i have "Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin/app/card/add/
Exception Value: " ;

in py manage.py shell i create 2 new models (card, deck) and it's ok! I think the point is that when saving the Card, the string (id) is passed to the deck field, but do you need int? Or something like that? Do I really have to make my own admin page and override the methods for saving models there?

Comment: Did you use the `python manage.py makemigrations` and `migrate` commands?

Comment: yeah. i can't get it. why the shell-way to add models is working, and standart admin doesn't

Comment: Provide your `admin.py` file, thanks.

Comment: `from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Comment, News, Card, Deck

admin.site.register(Comment)
admin.site.register(News)
admin.site.register(Card)
admin.site.register(Deck)`

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895320/how-do-i-fix-django-db-utils-databaseerror